# OpenBSD Kernel module calling network functions

Tags: c, sockets, bsd, openbsd

As a proof-of-concept, plus a handy paranoid tool, I'm writing an OpenBSD LKM that will connect to an IRC channel, and report when hooked syscalls are executed.

This is so I can essentially have a 'live' update of filesystem changes, user logons, etc., when I'm offsite but have internet access.

I've gotten as far as connecting the socket, but am stuck at trying to perform the equivalent of a `getaddrinfo` or even `inet_addr` call with a hardcoded address.

As these are userland functions, any attempts to use them will result in undefined references - fair enough. The trouble is, after a while of Googling and grep'ing the openbsd source, I cannot find any equivalent kernel functions to do this; the best recommendation has been to reimplement them in the module.

This means I need to also implement things like `islower`, `isxdigit` and `isspace` (and probably others as I progress), which gets a bit much to perform something so simple; is anyone aware of a workaround or alternative for this, or am I stuck c+p code from the net files?

Comment: Instead of letting the kernel module communicate directly with the server, why not let it open some local communication channel (e.g. a pipe or local socket) and have a userland application do the actual server communication?

Comment: Why would the kernel need to perform DNS lookups? And why would you be paranoid enough to be concerned with syscalls being executed, but trusting enough that your DNS system isn't spoofable?

Comment: I wanted to minimize the amount of dependencies the module had (pretty much to the point of being standalone) - I have a distrust of using data from userland in the kernel, even after validation. However, you're quite right in that the userland comms is the preferred and recommended method to do this, I just like being different.

Comment: "different" does not always mean "a better idea": http://media.photobucket.com/image/unique%20fork/speedy_2/unique-fork.jpg

Comment: Very true :D - the DNS lookups aren't that much of a concern to be honest, as I've stored the IPs for all the networks servers from prior calls (over years), and have them on my internal DNS server. This is why using a hardcoded address won't be too problematic - of course you then have the usual malicious/hijacked server to deal with..

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely better done in userspace. Regardless, OpenBSD no longer supports kernel modules.

Not that you're working on this project anymore. I just wanted to answer so that this could be closed, and so that I could clarify how to use some stdlib functions in the kernel.

In response to this:

> This means I need to also implement things like islower, isxdigit and isspace (and probably others as I progress), which gets a bit much to perform something so simple; is anyone aware of a workaround or alternative for this, or am I stuck c+p code from the net files?

Some C stdlib functions are available from libkern (see `libkern(9)`). Others, including many of the ctype functions like `islower()`, are available from libsa. To use these, you need something like:

```
#include <lib/libkern/libkern.h>
#include <lib/libsa/stand.h>
```

libsa contains a handful of headers (found in `/usr/src/sys/lib/libsa/`), so include each one you need.